# Opencart 3 - display a <div> section if product is linked to a certain category

Tags: php, twig, opencart, opencart-3

I'm trying display a div section floating above all products' image if the product is linked to a certain category.

on category.twig file I've added the following code

```
... <div class="product-thumb row">
        <div class="image"> 
<div class="freeship"><i class="fa fa-truck"></i> Free Shipping</div>...
```

I'm sure what should I do to only display the div.freeship on products that belong to a category ID 5.

anyone help appreciated!

Comment: What specifc version in Opencart 3 ?

Answer (score 1):

In your `category.php` controller file, **find**:

```
$data['products'][] = array(
```

**Replace** it with:

```
$freeship = false;
$product_categories = $this->model_catalog_product->getCategories($result['product_id']);
foreach ($product_categories as $product_category) {
    if ($product_category['category_id'] == 5) {
        $freeship = true;
        break;
    }
}
$data['products'][] = array(
    'freeship' => $freeship,
```

And in your `category.twig` view file, use it:

```
{% if product.freeship %}<div class="freeship"><i class="fa fa-truck"></i> Free Shipping</div>{% endif %}
```

Then refresh your modifications and theme cache.

Comment: Thanks DigiCart, Would this work on product page as well?

Comment: No, it's for category page. but you can use it in other pages with some edits.

Comment: I was able to do it to special pages, search, and manufacturers. but not to Products and Featured Modules, does it take too many changes?